# Why is Sound.SE "Uncategorized"?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

On https://stackexchange.com/sites, if you click on [Uncategorized](https://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized-newest), you find that [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) is the only site classified as such. It seems like this might be an oversight, given that the closely-related [AVP](https://video.stackexchange.com/) site is classified under [Life/Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts-newest). If it isn't an oversight, why isn't it categorized under Life/Arts or one of the other categories?

Comment: Clearly this is not a bug at all. May be a feature request?

Comment: I think the reason is because the transition of the site to the network is not yet complete, see Tim [answer to other question about that site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214455/152859).

Comment: @AnnaLear But now ja.SO is uncategorized?

Comment: @Fundamental That's unrelated, but [also fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246606/155160).

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know when it happened, but now [Sound Design SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) is categorized under [Technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#technology).