# Why are new sites classified as "uncategorized"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

I can imagine that it is a little bit hard if you're not a native Japanese or Russian speaker to figure out where those new sites are and what they are about. Putting them under uncategorized is not what those new sites deserve.

> [image: example of jp.so]      [image]

I understand from previous incidents [that sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214752/why-is-sound-se-uncategorized) that [don't follow the standard process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245386/whats-with-the-japanese-sos-stats#comment803228_245386) end up in this category for a while.

Can we make sure that new sites get properly categorized?

Comment: Don't forget to [check recent rep changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233645/green-rep-rectangle-sticks-out-a-little) sometimes ;)

Comment: It's not rude, it's just one of a plethora of things that still need to be done before the site is completely baked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed, and it will appropriately appear under "Technology" but it will take a bit of time for the stackexchange.com cache to drop and refresh the current site list.

Comment: umm... no. It's still not fixed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kOq2u.png (unless the cache takes 6-8 years to refresh?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard indeed - something else is hung here, I'll investigate and fix tomorrow.

Comment: Still the same. That [reminds me](http://www.commitstrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Strips-Erreur-masqu%C3%A9e-550-finalenglish.jpg) :)

Comment: Tomorrow has an interesting meaning.

Comment: 2 Peter 3:8 But do not forget this one thing, dear friends: With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day.

Comment: I wonder when Nick will notice the comments here? */hides*

Comment: Today the part of Nick Craver will be played by yours truly. Just pushed a fix for the category issue. :)

Comment: @rene It's known and we'll fix it - the code should actually already be in... Lemme try a build and see if that fixes the category.

Answer (score 11):

It's simply an artifact of going 'out of the box' to stand up a site. Our system is built around:

- Site topic is proposed on Area 51
- Said topic is vetted with a clear statement of purpose and audience
- A private beta for the site is brought up
- If all goes well, site goes into public

Our international sites are developed and tested on our *development* tier, which short circuits a lot of things that happen as a 'normal' site would go through the typical phases. We take it straight from the dev tier into production when it is ready for private / public beta, which means some manual backfill is needed.

It's exacerbated a bit for sites that have no obvious parent 'proposal' on Area 51.

As everything technically works just fine, said manual backfill isn't *exactly* the highest priority when we're still working on translations and promotional efforts. It'll be tucked away all nice and proper in the near future, no need to worry :)

Comment: Any plans to fix the site age? It appears as being 2013 years old in the main Stack Exchange portal's list of sites.